# ¿Como mostrar las coordenadas guardadas en la BD Mysql en Google Maps?

Tags: php, mysql

como puedo mostrar las coordenadas que tengo almacenadas en la base de datos Mysql y mostrarlas en Google maps mediante PHP? o como se debe de realizar?

Comment: debes realizar con javascript y la api de google maps https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map